# Do my PC specs meet the requirements to make Minecraft playable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I recently bought MC java, and so far it was fun.
However, my PC being a potato, it lagged a LOT. And I mean a LOT.
DO you think my current specs are enough to play MC?
GPU: Nvidia GEFORCE 9200
Ram: 2 GB (1.75 usable)
Processor: Unknown? ( can't find it in anything )

Do these specs meet the requirements to enjoyably run Minecraft Java Edition?

Comment: 2GB??!?!? Wait how old is your PC, I haven't even heard of less than 8 much less 2!?! Are you running MS-DOS or something?

Comment: It's an old Dell studio 1. I would say 10 years? (I know, it sucks.) and no, I am running goddamned windows 10

Comment: sorry didnt mean to flex on ur pc xD

Comment: i look at my pc specs, and then this and like i think you should get a new pc

Comment: Yeah I mean Im not sure its really possible, I have 16gb of ram and both 8gb and 16gb are the common ones nowadays, youre not really gonna be able to play well with 2gb

Comment: Consider installing version 1.12.2 or even older. You'll miss some features but the performance will be significantly better. Or consider upgrading RAM to at least 6GB. Minecraft should run quite smoothly if you allocate 4GB to it.

Comment: This duplicate is wrong. That asks for a way to know if something *will* work, not what minimum requirements are

Answer (score 0):

No, the ram and processor are the main problems of these "lag" issues. In general, most people have 8GB of ram.

Comment: Not necessarily, I used to play Minecraft on 4G of RAM and a lot of people would be okay with using 2G on a server. I do agree that 2G is about the limit for clients though

Comment: @Ben when was that? Nowadays with 1.13+ that's really hardly possible

Comment: @Penguin The default RAM allocation is still -Xmx1G afaik. This is definitely pushing it on a 2G system but 4G is definitely enough, assuming Minecraft is all you have open

Comment: @Ben windows is a huge memory hog, which doesnt matter too much with 8+ but youre really cutting it close with 4

Comment: I guess I haven't used windows in a while, I wasn't aware of this. Perhaps someone could provide some information about how to reduce the memory footprint for players like this with much less powerful machines?

Comment: @Ben 2 gb, not 1. dunno what launcher your using

Comment: pretty much every other less-memory intensive launcher doesn't support Microsoft login, which is what I use.